# Does Healing Wave grant Solar when drones are at full health?

Tags: awesomenauts

Voltar's [Healing Wave](http://awesomenauts.wikia.com/wiki/Healing_Wave) gives you Solar every time you heal a player or drone on your team. **Does this work when the ally is already at full health?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Patch 2.10 (released June 10, 2015), Voltar's Healing Wave has been replaced with a new auto-attack called [Techno Synaptic Wave](http://awesomenauts.gamepedia.com/Techno_Synaptic_Wave). This attack no longer provides Solar when used to heal an ally, and no longer heals droids at all, instead being usable to deal damage to enemies without any upgrades, along with other changes.

Answer (score 7):

After playing with Voltar quite a bit yesterday, my observations show that you do not gain any extra Solar when healing a player or drone that's already at full health.  You'll get the healing numbers popping up, but no extra solar is generated.